# Creating opaque datasets in a group

Tags: java, hdf5

I fail to understand why my code is giving me HDF5 Library Exceptions. It points at the `createScalarDS` method as the source of the error. But I believe this method does exist. Can anyone tell me why this code is unable to create an opaque dataset? What should the modification(s) be? Thanks.

```
public static void createFile(Message message) throws Exception {
    // retrieve an instance of H5File
    FileFormat fileFormat = FileFormat
            .getFileFormat(FileFormat.FILE_TYPE_HDF5);
    if (fileFormat == null) {
        System.err.println("Cannot find HDF5 FileFormat.");
        return;
    }

    // create a new file with a given file name.
    H5File testFile = (H5File) fileFormat.create(fname);
    if (testFile == null) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create file:" + fname);
        return;
    }

    // open the file and retrieve the root group
    testFile.open();
    Group root = (Group) ((javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode) testFile
            .getRootNode()).getUserObject();
    Group g1 = testFile.createGroup("byte arrays", root);

    // obtaining the serialized object
    byte[] b = serializer.serialize(message);
    int len = b.length;
    byte[] dset_data = new byte[len + 1];

    // Initialize data.
    int indx = 0;
    for (int jndx = 0; jndx < len; jndx++)
        dset_data[jndx] = b[jndx];
    dset_data[len] = (byte) (indx);

    // create opaque dataset ---- error here…
    Datatype dtype = testFile.createDatatype(Datatype.CLASS_OPAQUE,
            (len * 4), Datatype.NATIVE, Datatype.NATIVE);
    Dataset dataset = testFile.createScalarDS("byte array", g1, dtype,
            dims1D, null, null, 0, dset_data);// error shown in this line

    // close file resource
    testFile.close();
}
```

Comment: What error does the line show?

Comment: it gives me an HDF5LibraryException

Answer (score 0):

I don't have grip on HDF5.

but, you can not directly use CLASS_OPAQUE

An opaque data type is a user-defined data type that can be used in the same way as a built-in data type. To create an opaque type check links:

http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/Opaque_Datatypes.html

**To create array datatype object:**

```
Result = H5T_ARRAY_CREATE(Datatype_id, Dimensions)
```

**example:**

http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/H5F_CREATE.html

Comment: @Riddhish..I was able to create the opaque dataset normally in a file. But I wish to **create many datasets in a single file**. Since the dataset to file ratio is 1:1, I thought of using **groups** for you **can have multiple datasets** under a group. And so I was trying to implement CLASS_OPAQUE to create and opaque dataset under the group, but apparently there is some **library exception** which I am just unable to set straight.